# How to avoid always entering passphrase for id_rsa on terminal startup?

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, ssh-keys, passphrase

Currently every time I start up terminal I get prompted the following:

> Last login: Mon Nov 28 21:32:16 on ttys000
>
> Agent pid 2733
>
> Enter passphrase for /Users/my_name/.ssh/id_rsa:

Could you please guide me on how I can avoid having to enter a passphrase everytime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably wrote to your `~/.bashrc` lines

```
`eval ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

or something like this. This means that it will start a new `ssh-agent` for every shell you open, which is certainly not what you want. The agent should start when you open your Xsession (`~/.xsession`), or you should check if the agent is running before running a new one:

```
[ -z $SSH_AUTH_SOCK ] && `eval ssh-agent` && ssh-add
```

Comment: Perfect. This worked! and you were right, in my .bash_profile I had:

eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 7):

You could add your passphrase to your keychain:

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Or you can add it in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
UseKeychain yes
```

Comment: This is mac specific though. It doesn't work on Linux and other unix systems.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ssh-agent`. The man-page says :

> ssh-agent is a program to hold private keys used for public key
>   authenti‐
>        cation (RSA, DSA, ECDSA, Ed25519).  ssh-agent is usually started in the
>        beginning of an X-session or a login session, and all other windows or
>        programs are started as clients to the ssh-agent program.  Through use of
>        environment variables the agent can be located and automatically used for
>        authentication when logging in to other machines using ssh(1).

On further reading you can see :

> The agent initially does not have any private keys.  Keys are added
>   using
>        ssh-add(1).  When executed without arguments, ssh-add(1) adds the files
>        ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and
>        ~/.ssh/identity.  **If the identity has a passphrase, ssh-add(1) asks for
>        the passphrase on the terminal if it has one or from a small X11 program**
>        if running under X11.  If neither of these is the case then the authenti‐
>        cation will fail.  It then sends the identity to the agent.  Several
>        identities can be stored in the agent; the agent can automatically use
>        any of these identities.  ssh-add -l displays the identities currently
>        held by the agent.